# jsTree 3.3.2 - How to configure jsTree so that only some nodes are draggable and can be dropped at a certain level

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a tree like this:

```
ROOT
|---n1-1
      |---n2-1
            |---n3-1
      |---n2-2
            |---n3-2
|---n1-2
      |---n2-3
      |---n2-4
            |---n3-3
            |---n3-4
```

Is it possible to configure jsTree so that only n3-x nodes are draggable and they can only be dropped as n2-x node's children?

Answer (score 1):

On jsTree's [documentation](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=$.jstree.defaults.dnd&f=$.jstree.defaults.dnd.is_draggable), it points out a configuration option for the drag and drop plugin called $.jstree.defaults.dnd.is_draggable:

> A function invoked each time a node is about to be dragged, invoked in the tree's scope and receives the nodes about to be dragged as an argument (array) and the event that started the drag - return false to prevent dragging

You should be able to write a function which will check if it is an n3-x node.

I unfortunately don't see anything for specifying where it can be dropped within the documentation, but it looks like elsewhere on StackOverflow someone has solved this: [dnd, how to restrict dropping to certain node types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000095/dnd-how-to-restrict-dropping-to-certain-node-types)